# What size/type of window header beam do I need?

Tags: structural, load-bearing, beam, engineering, span-tables

I'm looking for some help specifying the type and dimensions of a new window header. The biggest complicating issue is that I only have 7.25" of depth to use for the new header.

The goal is to double the size of the window opening in a load-bearing, exterior, top-floor wall (only the 8:12 pitch roof above). The window header will need to go from a 5' span to a 10' span as seen here:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/rATPh3K.jpg]

This is what I know of the overall house structure:
[image]
(The window faces ENE)

This is an inside view of the project:
[image]

This is an outside view of the project:
[image]

The house is in Massachusetts and about 300 yards from the ocean, so there are snow and wind load considerations. I'm in the queue for a couple local structural engineers, but there are not many in my area and consequently, they are generally booked out months.

Thanks for your feedback, I appreciate your time.

Comment: Engineer would need span of rafters. but you are probably looking at a steel beam but they need 2x6  under it. so getting under 7.25 is probably not possible. Why not just have 2x4 between windows.  A window mullion is going to be 1.5 anyway.  Get a grade one southern yellow pine 2x4 and you can stain or paint it without cladding it.